# Babel preset es2015 loose not working?

Tags: babeljs

Is this `"loose": true` not working for the ["es2015" preset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015) or a mistake/misunderstanding on my part?

#### Input Code

I've tried with the [REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBA9gRgVhAvBCBvAvgbgFAHcCWALgBYAUscAlCqthMQKYA2TUEuUYTAJtukA) and on on the command line. I can't get babel to translate my loose javascript in *looseWith.js*:

```
var obj = {};
with (obj) {
}
```

*.babelrc* (attempt1):

```
{
    "presets": [
        [ "es2015", { "loose": true }]
    ]
}
```

*.babelrc* (attempt2 - as in [REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBA9gRgVhAvBCBvAvgbgFAHcCWALgBYAUscAlCqthMQKYA2TUEuUYTAJtukA)):

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015-loose"
    ]
}
```

I then try running either of these `.babelrc`s:

```
> babel looseWith.js 
SyntaxError: looseWith.js: 'with' in strict mode (2:0)
  1 | var obj = {};
> 2 | with (obj) {
    | ^
  3 | }
```

Seems to me that this is still in strict mode. The [documentation on loose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015#loose) is quite scarce and just says:

> Enable "loose" transformations for any plugins in this preset that allow them.

I'm trying to negate `use strict` :-) Is this my misunderstanding? What other meanings are there for "loose"?

I then tried adding `"modules": "umd"` to `.babelrc` to attempt1 above, and when fed with a proper strict .js file, it did produce umd output, so I think babel is picking up the `.babelrc`module just fine.

#### Background

I'm trying to be able to use ES6 in my underscore/lodash templates. The javascript output of e.g. `_.template(script).source` contains the "with" statement (by default). So I'm trying to use babel to translate ES6 - including the "with" statement - into ES5.

#### Environment

```
> node --version
v7.10.1

> cat package.json 
{
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-loose": "^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Babel really does not play well with `with` statements, even if you do enable the flags that make it parse successfully. If you're going to use `with` you'd be better to skip processing that file with Babel. `with` can't be analyzed statically, which is the whole reason it isn't allowed in strict mode, and also means Babel won't know how to transform stuff around it safely.